# C++ Lambda captures empty string

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I have a messagebox class with buttons that execute a given function upon being clicked:

```
// cMessage.h
#include "cButton.h"

class cMessage{
    public:
        std::vector<cButton*> button;
        cMessage(const std::vector<std::function<void()> >& effect);
        ~cMessage();
        void alert();};

// cMessage.cpp
cMessage::cMessage(const std::vector<std::function<void()> >& effect){
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < effect.size(); i++)
        button.push_back(new cButton(effect[i], this)); }

cMessage::~cMessage(){
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < button.size(); i++)
        delete button[i];}

void cMessage::alert(){
    delete this;}

// cButton.h
class cMessage;

class cButton{
    private:
        cMessage* alert;
        const std::function<void()> effect;
    public:
        cButton(const std::function<void()>& effect, cMessage* alert);
        void onClick();}

// cButton.cpp
cButton::cButton(const std::function<void()>& effect, cMessage* alert): effect(effect), alert(alert){}

void cButton::onClick(){
    if(alert)  alert->alert();
    if(effect) effect();}
```

The problem occurs when I pass a lambda function, because when I let that lambda function capture a pair consisting of a string and an unsigned int, the string is empty the moment the function is executed. The unsigned int, however, is still 1.

```
// main.cpp
#include "cMessage.h"    

int main(){
    cMessage* message;
    {const pair<const string, const unsigned int> var("test", 1);
     std::function<void()> f = [var](){ std::cout << var.first << std::endl << var.second << std::endl; } };
     message = new cMessage( {f} );}
    message->button[0]->onClick();

    return 0;}
```

With some more couts I have found that in the constructor of cButton, the string is still "test".
Something that makes it even weirder is that when I directly construct a button, the problem does not occur.

**Problem Solved**
It was caused by undefined behavior because the lambda function was called after the button had been deleted (The button had made a call to its message just before that causing it to be deleted). This also explains why directly creating a button doesn't give problems. It surprises me that I didn't have any other problems with that yet. Thanks for all your help

Comment: You should create http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. What compiler do you use?

Comment: MinGW, and this is actually the minimal code that produces the error

Comment: What is the type of `effect`?

Comment: It should be minimal **complete** code

Comment: @RTCgee The goal of MCVE is for me to literally copy your code into my window and compile/run it, to see if I can "verify" your issue.

Comment: I'll add the class definitions then

Comment: Any chance you're a LISPer? Seeing this indentation and bracket style in C++ code confuses the hell out of me.

Comment: There are still essential parts missing/inconsistent after your edit. E.g. the `cMessage` constructor expects a vector, but you don't pass one in your `main`. `cButton::onClick` is never called. Please provide the **actual** code.

Comment: @reima I got it to compile http://ideone.com/070FxL but it doesn't seem to show the behaviour RTCgee describes.

Comment: @sjdowling Then the error most likely lies in the parts RTCgee did change or not include in the question.

Comment: I do pass it a vector (initializer list) and to show how onclick is called would make it too complex

Comment: @RTCgee: My bad, didn't see the initializer list. Still, `size` is undefined in the constructor. Includes are missing. Please don't let us guess these things and provide a complete example. If you can't show us how `onClick` is called, we cannot possibly help you any further. Try to simplify your code.

Comment: I think this code will still produce the problem, I think the pair going out of scope is an important event.

Comment: [Strange, it works for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8a1aeede2aa2be66)

Comment: Hm... it works for me too, currently looking at what I left out

Comment: It works for me too. When the pair goes out of scope it has already been copied to the lamba expression object.

Comment: The problem is that it does go wrong and the code I posted is the only code that influences the outcome

Comment: The classes now are exactly like I have them, except for some graphical things of which I am sure that they in no way influence the outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest re-thinking

```
new cButton(this, effect[i]);
```

Otherwise share more of the code.

--- edit ---

The code you pasted [appears to produce the right output](https://ideone.com/3BYTRG):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <utility>

class cButton{
    private:
        const std::function<void()> effect;
    public:
        cButton(const std::function<void()>& effect);
        void onClick();};

cButton::cButton(const std::function<void()>& effect): effect(effect){}


class cMessage{
    public:
        std::vector<cButton*> button;
        cMessage(const std::vector<std::function<void()> >& effect);};


cMessage::cMessage(const std::vector<std::function<void()> >& effect){
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < effect.size(); i++)
        button.push_back(new cButton(effect[i])); }


void cButton::onClick(){
    if(effect) effect();
    }

int main(){
    cMessage* message{};
    {
        const std::pair<const std::string, const unsigned int> var("test", 1);
        std::function<void()> f = [var](){ std::cout << var.first << std::endl << var.second << std::endl; };
        message = new cMessage( {f} );
    } 
    message->button[0]->onClick();
}

Output:
test
1
```

Comment: I have found the problem, the new cButton(this, effect[i]); part was essential: with the this argument the button would alert the message when it was pressed. The message then deleted all buttons and itself. But after having called this alert function, the button still used some of its member functions, resulting in undefined behavior.